# How to limit the depth of the @Fetch annotation in Spring data neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I know that the [@Fetch annotation can be used to load nodes on the other sides of relationships](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#d5e262).  Normally, it appears just the ID of the foreign node is loaded, and not its properties.

Is there a way to limit the depth of @Fetch so that only the first neighbor is loaded, and no further?  In a heavily connected graph, we don't want to load the entire graph of course, but to minimize the number of calls back to the server, very often it's useful for that first level of connected nodes to be included in a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way of limiting the depth, `@Fetch` goes along to the next object and if that one has again `@Fetch` annotations it will continue to load. It might not have been the wisest decision to do so, but that's the way it currently is in SDN3.

In SDN4 you have the option to specify a depth parameter for load and store methods.

I'm not a big fan of navigation / loading of nested structures via domain objects.

That's why I'd rather recommend for nested loading to write a use-case specific cypher query to load the data you need and project it into a DTO which is annotated with `@QueryResult` as part of a repository method.

```
interface MovieRespository extends GraphRepository<Movie> {
    @Query("MATCH (n:Actor)-->(m:Movie) return n.name as name,collect(m.title) as titles")
    List<Filmography> listFilmographies(Pageable page);
} 
@QueryResult class Filmography {
   String name;
   List<String> titles;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I'm not a big fan of navigation / loading of nested structures via domain objects"?

Answer (score 0):

Michael, so in SDN4, if you have a nested node as part of your model, then we will need to uniquely load this data to our nodes?

(I.e.

```
class Movie {

 @Relationship(type = "mpaa_classification", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
 Genre genre;
}
```

we will need to load the genre property as a separate call once we load the movie in question?

Answer (score 0):

Since SDN 4.2 or so, there seems to be an undocumented @Depth(n) Annotation which does exactly what you are looking for.